# AdWords clicks/cost lower than Google Analytics clicks/cost

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I'm having an issue where Google AdWords is reporting fewer clicks/cost than what is shown in Google Analytics clicks and cost.  I will take a 7 day range in AdWords and Analytics.  AdWords is usually reporting about 11%-14% fewer clicks and cost than Analytics.  The top 5 or so campaigns match exactly in AdWords and Analytics (i.e. campaign #1 shows 100 clicks and $100 cost in both GA and AdWords).

I've checked my code and the embed code is right before .

Only 1 AdWords account is linked to Google Analytics.

Is there anything else to check?  I don't expect the numbers to match exactly, but 11%-14% is a fairly big variation.  In my research, it seems like most users are having the inverse issue (more adwords clicks/cost than analytics clicks/cost)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem but a business application issue that should, instead, be asked on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check invalid click activity. You can enable this in your columns and also check the billing activity to see if there are any refunds from Google for invalid activity. Google AdWords removes those data from your reporting and Google Analytics don't.